# Find the total number of permutations in which letters of the word $ARRANGEMENT$ can be permuted so that two $E$s and two $R$s do not come together.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Find the total number of permutations in which letters of the word $ARRANGEMENT$ can be permuted  so that two $E$s and two $R$s do not come together.

MY TRY:

Total number of arrangements possible=$\dfrac{11!}{2!2!2!2!}=2494800$

Number of arrangements that are possible from two $E$s and two $R$s =$\dfrac{4!}{2!2!}=6$

Now if we treat two $E$s and two $R$s as one unit then number of possible arrangements=$\dfrac{6.8!}{2!2!}=60480$

Total number of required permutations$= 2494800-60480=2434320$

But the answer provided by the text does not match my answer.  Please correct me.

Comment: What do you mean by the $E$s and the $R$s not coming together? Can $\cdots ER\cdots$ appear in the word?

Comment: Please define the "never coming together" part more specifically. Thank you.

Comment: Question Editted...

Comment: I still do not understand what do you mean by that. Can $ \cdots EE \cdots RR \cdots $ or $ \cdots ER \cdots ER \cdots $ appear in the word? Or do you mean 4 of them must be separated?

Comment: Or do you mean all combinations are possible, and just cases where "$EERR$" is grouped together cannot happen?

Comment: This is exactly how the book puts it.

Comment: OK... what is the answer that the book gave?

Comment: Answer is 1678320

Comment: Based on the answer, the intended question was:  Find the number of distinguishable arrangements of the word ARRANGEMENT in which the two $E$s are not consecutive and the two $R$s are not consecutive.  The condition is violated if the two $E$s are consecutive or the two $R$s are consecutive, which requires the use of the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle.